# Acelerar respuesta del servidor

Tags: php, java, android, sql, kotlin

Un saludo a todos, tengo una app que obtiene gran parte de su contenido desde una base de datos por medio de un webservice, el inconveniente que veo últimamente es que el tiempo de carga de los elementos se demora mucho en comparación al tiempo de respuesta que veo al momento de consultar lo mismo en el phpMyAdmin, la solicitud la estoy haciendo desde android con Volley, cree un Syngleton ya que son diferentes secciones (en la app) con diferente contenido.

Poco he utilizado php y no se si lo he hecho de la forma correcta, leí que el archivo (php) debe estar optimizado para procesar la solicitud rápidamente, este es uno de mis archivos php.

```
<?php
$content = $_REQUEST['t'];

switch ($content){

case 'spanish':
read_content_addons('**Nombre de la table**');
break;

case 'english':
read_content_addons('**Nombre de la table**');
break;

case 'music':
read_content_addons('**Nombre de la table**');
break;

case 'list':
read_content_list();
break;

case 'builds':
read_content_builds();
break;

case 'notice':
read_content_new();
break;
}

function read_content_addons($tab){

include("conex.php");

$res = $conex->query("SELECT `id`, `name`, `content`, `instalation`, `patch`, `logo`, `status`, `user`, `likes`
FROM $tab WHERE `status`=1 ORDER BY $tab.`id` DESC");

$datos = array();

foreach ($res as $row) {
    $datos[] = $row ;  
 }
echo json_encode($datos, true); 
}

function read_content_list(){

include("conex.php");

$res = $conex->query("SELECT `id`, `name`, `path`, `likes`, `user`, `status`
FROM `**Nombre de la table**` WHERE `status`=1 ORDER BY `**Nombre de la table**`.`id` DESC");

$datos = array();

foreach ($res as $row) {
    $datos[] = $row ;  
 }
echo json_encode($datos, true); 
}

function read_content_builds(){

include("conex.php");

$res = $conex->query("SELECT `id`, `name`, `path`, `url_img`, `likes`, `user`, `status` FROM `**Nombre de la table**` WHERE `status`=1 ORDER BY `**Nombre de la table**`.`id` DESC");

$datos = array();

foreach ($res as $row) {
    $datos[] = $row ;  
 }
echo json_encode($datos, true); 
}

function read_content_new(){

include("conex.php");

$res = $conex->query("SELECT * FROM `notices` WHERE 1 ORDER BY `**Nombre de la table**`.`id` DESC");

//echo $res->errorInfo();

$datos = array();

foreach ($res as $row) {
    $datos[] = $row ;  
 }
echo json_encode($datos, true); 

}
```

Esta es la forma en que envió la solicitud al webservice

```
val url = "${Utils().url_conex}read_content.php"
    val postRequest = object : StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, Response.Listener<String> {

        Log.i("prueba", "Read spanish -> $it")
        dataAddonsSpanish = it
        loadData()

    }, Response.ErrorListener { }) {

        override fun getParams(): MutableMap<String, String> {

            val params = hashMapOf<String, String>()
            params["t"] = table

            return params
        }
    }

    postRequest.retryPolicy = DefaultRetryPolicy(0, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT)
    MySingletonVolley.getInstance(activity!!).addToRequest(postRequest)
```

Mil gracias por sus respuestas, me gustaría saber si esta correctamente todo o si estoy generando alguna carga adicional al hacer los procesos en el servidor ya que si hago la misma consulta en el myPhpAdmin por SQL su demora es de 0.0004, entiendo que se debe demorar un poco mas en el proceso del webservice y la conexión que tenga el usuario, pero en mi caso he visto demoras de hasta 8 segundos (o mas) con una conexión de 20Mb y el tamaño de la tabla de 20KB.

*Agrego la etiqueta Java ya que si la solución esta en ese lenguaje lo manejo perfectamente*

Comment: ¿Haz probado llamar el webservice desde el browser o con curl? Es decir fuera de la app y fuera del servidor. ¿Cuánto tarda?

Comment: @Sal acabo de probar y su demora es muy poca, diría que menos de un segundo.

Comment: Depende, trata de hacer recursiva las peticiones de tu webservice, tal vez nunca dejes a que tu primera solicitud termine cuando ya estás mandando a llamar las siguientes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

puedes hacerlo asi:
mejore lo que pude entender de tu codigo menos evaluaciones, y las solicitudes que no cumplan los campos no sera del todo procesadas por lo que reducira la carga del servidor!

```
<?php

// si no se envia nada para que ejecutar todo el codigo?
if (empty($_REQUEST['t'])) {
    // especificamos el error
    $datos["error"] = "ups! no hemos recibido nada!";
    // terminamos la ejecucion y retornamos el error
    die(json_encode($datos, true)); 
}

// si se envio algo empezmos a evaluar
include("conex.php");
// contendara nuestro resultados o errores
$datos = array();

//un filtro para evitar sql injection
$content = filter_var($_REQUEST['t'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

// querys preparadas 
$builds = "SELECT `id`, `name`, `path`, `url_img`, `likes`, `user`, `status` FROM `%s` WHERE `status`=1 ORDER BY `%s`.`id` DESC";
$addons = "SELECT `id`, `name`, `content`, `instalation`, `patch`, `logo`, `status`, `user`, `likes` FROM %s WHERE `status`=1 ORDER BY %s.`id` DESC";
$list = "SELECT `id`, `name`, `path`, `likes`, `user`, `status` FROM `%s` WHERE `status`=1 ORDER BY `%s`.`id` DESC";
$new = "SELECT * FROM `notices` WHERE 1 ORDER BY `%s`.`id` DESC";

switch ($content){

    case 'spanish': 
        querys($addons,'tabla_4');
    break;

    case 'english':
        querys($addons,'tabla_3');
    break;

    case 'music':
        querys($addons,'tabla_2');
    break;

    case 'list':
        querys($list,"id");
    break;

    case 'builds':
        querys($builds,"tabla_1");
    break;

    case 'notice':
        querys($new,"status");
    break;
}


// creamos una funcion query que recibe la query y el argumento;
function querys($query,$arg){
    // creamos una variable $nq y con la funcion sprintf  remplazamos %s por el argumento
    $nq = sprintf($query,$arg);
    // ejecutamos la query
    $result = $conex->query($nq);

    // si se ejecuto correctamente entramos
    if($result){
        // si hubo por lo menos 1 resultado ejecutamos
        if($result->num_rows > 0){
            // recorremos el resultado y llenamos el arreglo $datos
            foreach ($result as $row) {
                $datos[] = $row;  
             }
             // cerramos la conexion
             $result->close();
             // retornamos los $datos en formato json
             return echo json_encode($datos, true); 
        }
    }

    // si no se ejecuto correctamente o hubo algun error retornamos entonces los errores
    $datos["error"] = sprintf("no se pudo ejecutar la query: %s", $conex->error);
    // retornamos los $datos en formato json
    return echo json_encode($datos, true); 
}
```

Comment: Agrega una explicación de lo que realiza el código y como ayudaría a solucionar el problema planteado, saludos.ç

Comment: la explicacion del codigo esta dentro del mismo por si no lo notastes en cuanto a en que mejora el lo planteado: menos evaluaciones  de codigo, menos procesamiento para solicitudes mal formuladas y menos uso de memoria para asignacion de variables! pero si esto no te comvence puedes correrle un test y veras la enorme diferencia entre el codigo anterior y este @Jorgesys saludos!